# Numbers of solutions to $x^3+x^2\equiv 3\pmod{3^{10}}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Numbers of solutions to $x^3+x^2\equiv 3\pmod{3^{10}}$ ?
First solve:
$$x^3+x^2\equiv 3\pmod{3}$$
Solutions are $x\equiv 0\pmod3$ and $x\equiv 2\pmod3$
Checking for mod $3^2$ , the $x\equiv 0\pmod3$ doesn’t work, and writing $x$ as $x=3k+2$ we get $k=3k_1$ when we solve mod $3^2$.
And now? I dont know what to do.

Comment: so $x\equiv2\mod 9$ solves $x^3+x^2\equiv3\mod9$; how about solving the congruence mod $27$?

Comment: That doesn’t work aswell. So it has 0 solutions?

Comment: no, the solution is $x\equiv20\mod{27}$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner oh yes , I found my mistake. So I need to check for every mod $3^k$ ?

Comment: Or I can use the Hensel Lemma, since $f’(2) wasnt congruent to 0 mod 3?

Comment: If you want to find the solution, solve modulo increasing powers of $3$; if you just want to know how many solutions there are, there is one, by Hensel's lemma

Comment: Thank you so much!!